# Questions about the Karma commit message convention

Tags: git, karma-runner, git-commit

About the Karma commit message convention:

> feat, fix, docs, style, refactor, test, chore

I'm in doubt which prefix to use in certain situations, such as:

1. I need to version a logic that complements an existing code.
2. I need to change the name of some variable.
3. I need to add or remove spaces in the code.
4. I need to add or remove comments in the code.
5. I need to change an HTML structure (change the order of some element or increment/decrement some attribute, for example).
6. I need to add a CSS code (change the color of some element or the layout, for example).
7. I need to version the service worker file (a script that the browser runs in the background).

**Convention References**

> [Convenção de mensagens de commit - Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/dev/git-commit-msg.html)

Answer (score 2):

My point of view:

1. I don't understand well what you mean...
2. Refactor
3. Style
4. Refactor, docs or chore
5. If the behaviour is the same, refactor. Otherwise, fix.
6. Fix or feat
7. Fix or feat

Comment: For example, I implemented a login feature and then commit a session control. It's related...

Comment: It's "feat" then.